# What is Business Data Web Parts?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to display the record which i select in my List View Web Part to my Business Related List Web Part how can i do this? When i connection this two WebPart that time external list web part not showing all the columns.Why?
[image]

Comment: all the columns? A webpart shows always a view which mostly consists of not all the columns. Or do you mean that the view on the webpart is not completely shown?

Comment: Hey please check this http://prnt.sc/cg1gtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is Business Data Web Parts?**

Bussiness data is a category located when you try to Display business data on a SharePoint site from External lists , Excel , Visio as shown below.

[image]

Regarding `connectivity`

These Web Parts support Web Part connections and make it easier to create Master-Detail applications without writing any code. For example, you can display customers and their details using the Business Data List and Business Data Item Web Parts by simply connecting them. These Web Parts can also be integrated in dashboards.

For more details check [Business Data Web Parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms521389(v=office.12).aspx)

To make connection try to use `Business Data List Web Part` rather than `Business Data Related List` as (Consumer) it will show the ID that should be connected directly with corresponding value at your list view web part (Provider). but I think it's not working with a custom list as I mentioned above in connectivity section.

For more details check [Display business data on a SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-business-data-on-a-SharePoint-site-7ef2dd1b-7b1e-4946-a256-ade32b8606e6)